# Updating UITextView inside UIScrollView while scrolling makes the scrollView stop scrolling

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, scroll

- I have a **scrollView** that contains 12 **UIViews** set as tiles. Each tile contains a textView.
- The scrollView has pagination enabled. So, you have 12 tiles per page and you scroll horizontally.
- I am updating the textView whenever I receive information from an API call.

This is updating the textView correctly, but I have a huge problem. Whenever the update happens, the scrollView actually scrolls to the view that was just updated. So whenever I load a new column of tiles, the scrollview stops when it begins loading it, even if it has momentum!

Any idea what might be causing this?

If I lazy load the cells without any information in them everything works right, so I'm thinking it has to do with me updating the textView.

I have already tried:

- Using an **NSTimer** (and setting its mode to NSRunLoopCommonModes).
- Using an **NSOperationQueue** and calling the main thread whenever I need to update UI changes.

None of those worked.

Comment: My solution was to change the UITextView to a UILabel and nothing happened. I'm keeping this open in case anyone actually has an answer.

Comment: Are you saying changing to UILabel fixed the problem or not?  Try changing the UITextView editable property to NO while it is being updated and see if that helps.  Make sure the delegate on the UITextView is set to nil when updating the text value.

Answer (score 0):

i think the solution lies within your post: 
"Using an `NSOperationQueue` and calling the main thread whenever I need to update UI changes."

Whenever scrollView calls for willScroll, stop the current Images being downloaded & when the scroll view stops scroll & its delegate method is called start the new queue to download images.

Comment: I have removed the NSOperationQueue (everything is on the main thread now) and it's still not working.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion will be debugging it using instrument. In instrument there is a trace template named "Time profiler", you can actually see how much time your application spends on each tasks. 
But if you are updating the textViews, of course the main thread will be blocked, so the scroll view stop scrolling until all the textViews are updated. So my suggestion will be tweaking the performance.
Maybe you are loading too much things in each textView?

Comment: I'm only updating the textViews' text property. Unfortunately, I don't have time for a response soon, but I'll be sure to update this post (as my comment up there states that I've changed it to UILAbel) with anything I eventually find.